What might be causing ls to ignore LS_COLORS for setgid (sg, g+s) directories?
Trying to show setgid in a different color and failing.
tried with the minimum:
LS_COLORS="sg:41;41" ls -la --color=auto But still got regular directory colors for a setgid (chmod g+s) directory.
Then tried with dircolors, first outputed the "template" with dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors, edited only the setgid line, and eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)
# ~/.dircolors
…
SETGID 30;44 # file that is setgid (g+s)                                                                                                                              
…

it produces:
env | grep LS_
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;44:ca=00:tw=30;42:ow=30;44;01:st=30;44;01:ex=01;32:*.7z=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.apk=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.crate=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.drpm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.egg=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.pyz=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.tar=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.udeb=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.whl=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.avif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:*~=00;90:*#=00;90:*.bak=00;90:*.crdownload=00;90:*.dpkg-dist=00;90:*.dpkg-new=00;90:*.dpkg-old=00;90:*.dpkg-tmp=00;90:*.old=00;90:*.orig=00;90:*.part=00;90:*.rej=00;90:*.rpmnew=00;90:*.rpmorig=00;90:*.rpmsave=00;90:*.swp=00;90:*.tmp=00;90:*.ucf-dist=00;90:*.ucf-new=00;90:*.ucf-old=00;90:

tried more obvious colors 41;41 (red on red)  but nothing.
It does works fine for files, just not for directories.
Here are some screenshots. D1 is a dir with setgid.

same with tree just to make sure this is not something isolated to ls

on the tests above I use su too, because both su and sg are gnu bash extensions not available on other shells.
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 9.5
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.



I think it may be a matter of precedence (directories match di first) - a previous question precedence of dircolors went unanswered though

@steeldriver good point! Didn't think about this. But, the test is with only a single value (there no di on the screenshots). So it might not be that. Tested adding di to set dirs as red, both before and after sg. nothing changed.

(1) Why do you believe that Bash has anything to do with the handling of LS_COLORS?  (2) Your question would be clearer if you said what results you were expecting.  In particular, what do you expect 41;41 to do?  (3) Have you tried a setgid file?  If the problem is just setgid directories, then your question is actively misleading.   (4) You say “there [is] no di on the screenshots”.  Huh?  Your env command shows di=01;34, which seems to correspond to the bright blue foreground you are getting.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' thanks for the notes. (a1) I don't know. added ls version too. (a2) I was trying any color that is not the default dir-blue... 41:41 is all red.  (a3) indeed setguid files work fine! (a4) i did unset LS_COLORS! that color is the default from ls i guess? You can see it doesn't show up on tree. I've updated the question with your very good points.

If you mean ALL red (i.e., red foreground and red background, i.e., unreadable), wouldn’t that need to be 31;41?

@steeldriver: The OP has confirmed that setgid files are displayed as specified by sg, so your insight probably is the answer.

This has nothing to do with bash: the ls command decides how it formats the output. GNU ls takes its color settings from the LS_COLORS variable, which is meant to be set by the dircolors command. The output of dircolors -p is the closest thing to documentation of dircolors.
# Below are the color init strings for the basic file types.
…
#FILE 00 # regular file: use no color at all
…
DIR 01;34 # directory
…
SETUID 37;41 # file that is setuid (u+s)
SETGID 30;43 # file that is setgid (g+s)
CAPABILITY 30;41 # file with capability
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 37;44 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;32

In the lines cited above, “file” means a regular file. Directories and other non-regular files are colored according to their type, not according to their permissions or name, except for sticky/other-writable directories as specified.
There is no setting for setgid directories, or for directories having peculiar access control lists.

$ dircolors -p | grep GID
SETGID 30;43 # file that is setgid (g+s)

We should probably improve that description to "regular file".
Note colors can get confusing and non standard quickly with the various combinations of file attributes. I prefer to just highlight appropriate parts of the default ls long format listing, with a wrapper script. My script already highlights SETGID for all file types. See:
https://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/l

I clarified that only regular files have SETGID colored at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/801792c69
